# Find rows of a matrix that belong to another one

Tags: matlab, sorting

I haven't been able to find existing sources about what i ask, though i think others have had that problem before, so feel free to mark as duplicate if it is and i'll delete this question.

I have two matrices :

`A` a `Mx5` matrix whose 4 first columns are integers and whose 5th column is filled with doubles.

`B` a `Nx4` matrix whose 4 columns are the same than the first 4 columns in A but in a different order and with some rows that don't belong to `A`(we always have `M<N`).

**What I want to do is :**

1. Get the indexes (with respect to the bigger matrix `B`), of the rows in `A` in which the 4 first values fit a row in `B`
2. Fill a `Nx1` vector with the values in the 5th column of `A` at the indexes where there was a matching row and zeros elsewhere.

I do have some working code here, but it's pretty slow as `N` will be at least 2 millions rows (Approx 7s, which is too big as the process will be repeated). Plus in order to do what i want, i for now have to sort the rows in both matrices with respect to the first 4 columns, thus taking even more time.

**Working code :**

```
N=size(B,1);
A=sortrows(A,1:4);
[B,ind]=sortrows(B);
[~,index]=sort(ind)
FinValues=zeros(N,1);
FinValues(ismember(B,A(:,1:4),'rows'))=A(:,5);
FinValues=FinValues(index);
```

**Toy example :**

```
A= [134 3 16998 2 2.0234e-2;...
    134 2 15557 1 3.0234e-3];

B=[17778 1 16559 4;...
   134 2 15557 1;...
   134 3 16998 2;...
   15554 2 16998 3];
```

**Desired output :**

```
FinValues=

0
3.0234e-3  
2.0234e-2
0
```

I hope this is clear enough, thanks in advance!

Comment: Your working code is missing the definition of `N` and for your toy example outputs `FinValues = [0.0030 0.0202 0 0];` - different order.

Comment: check this post... this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33316919/find-the-rows-of-a-matrix-with-conditions-concerning-the-values-of-certain-colum/33317443#33317443

Comment: @IKavanagh : I added the definition of `N` in the code. The reason you have this output is that you redefined N but didn't clear the variables so `A` and `B` had been sorted. Clear variables and run again it should work ^^

Answer (score 2):

This should be quicker, as it completely removes the need for any sorting. We can use the second output argument of [`ismember`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) to find the indexes of the rows **immediately** and then use these to directly index `F` filling it with `A`.

```
>> [~, idx] = ismember(A(:, 1:4), B, 'rows');
>> F = zeros(N, 1);
>> F(idx) = A(:, 5)
F =
         0
    0.0030
    0.0202
         0
```

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what i wanted!! I'll run the time tests and put it in the comments, thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help. I'd be interested to see the timings.

Comment: It actually runs slower than the previous version.. Maybe the sorting helped `ismember` to go faster (Previous timing : 7.02s, New timing : 11.24s)

Comment: 50 times each and took the average time. I then ran the profiler and am quite surprised with the results : The sorted `ismember` call takes 2.9s where the unsorted one takes 6s!

Comment: How long do the sorts take? 5s for `F(idx)` sounds like its the issue.

Comment: I actually have to do all this twice. To compare comparable things : If i run your code on only 1 matrix it takes around 6s, while the 2 calls to sortrows plus the sorted ismember will take approx 4.9s.

Comment: I guess your way was faster all along then.